# MongooseError - Operation users.xxx() buffering timed out after 10000ms while connecting to mongoosedb NestJS test case in jest

Tags: mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I am trying to a write test case for a service method create that interacts with mongoosedb. Nest is unable to connect to the db and I notice `MongooseError - Operation users.xxx() buffering timed out after 10000ms` . I dont see the error when I run the application. Error is only seen when test case is excuted.

### test case

instead of connecting to mongoose directly, I am compiling a module.

```
//import statements

describe('user DB Service - Sample', () => {
    let service: DbService;
    let userConnection: Connection;
    const userModel = model('User', UserSchema);
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [
                MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/nest?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false', { connectionName: 'users', useNewUrlParser: true }),
            ],
            providers: [
                DbService,
                {
                    provide: getModelToken('User'),
                    useValue: userModel,
                },
            ],
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<DbService>(DbService);
        userConnection = await module.get(getConnectionToken('users'))
        jest.setTimeout(30000)

    });

    /**
     * create user
     */
    it('Create user with null input should return Invalid Input exception', async () => {
        try {

            let createRequest = {
                // user input object
            }
            idConnection.on('connect', () => {
                console.log('connected')
            })
            const result = await service.create(createRequest
            // validate result
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error creating', error)
            // error validation
        }
    });
}
```

### db service

```
//import statements

@Injectable()
export class DbService {

    constructor(@InjectModel('id') private readonly idModel: Model<IdDocument>) {
    }

    create(input: UserCreate) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                // create, save the doc and return doc to caller
                const userdoc = new this.idModel(input)
                const result = await userdoc.save({ validateBeforeSave: true })
                resolve(userdoc)
            } catch (error) {
                // send error to caller
                console.log('error while resolving promise' + JSON.stringify(error))
                reject(error)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: discord link https://discord.com/channels/520622812742811698/606125380817911828/845719193398804510

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right track, however, there are a few issues with your code which is making it difficult to test.

Firstly, there's no need to concern yourself with a database connection when unit testing. If you just need to ensure that your service method calls the model methods then you can do something like this:

### Service

```
@Injectable()
export class DbService { // consider naming this UserService

  constructor(@InjectModel('id') private readonly idModel: Model) {}

  async create(input: UserCreate) {
    try {
      const userdoc = new this.idModel(input);
      return userdoc.save()
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error while resolving promise' + JSON.stringify(error));
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Better yet, separate the concerns of your service with an exception filter and push error handling away from your service:

### ExceptionFilter

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DbService { // consider naming this UserService

  constructor(@InjectModel('id') private readonly idModel: Model) {}

  async create(input: UserCreate) {
    return new this.idModel(input).save();
  }
}
```

Filter:

```
@Catch(MongooseValidationError)
export class ValidationExceptionFilter extends BaseExceptionFilter {
  catch (exception: MongooseValidationError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const customError = new YourCustomError('Invalid!', 'you gave me invalid details!');
    super.catch(customError, host)
  }
}
```

Then, adapt your unit testing to use mocks instead of the real thing. Your integration (e2e) tests should ensure that a real database is used.

### Tests

```
//import statements

const data = {
  // ... a mock object
}

class mockModel {

     constructor(public data?: any) {}

     save() {
         return this.data;
     }

     static findOne({ _id }) {
         return data;
     }
}


describe('user DB Service - Sample', () => {
    let service: DbService;
    let model: Model;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                DbService,
                {
                    provide: getModelToken('User'),
                    useClass: mockModel // if it throws error use useValue
                },
            ],
        }).compile();


        service = module.get(DbService);
        model = module.get(getModelToken('User')); // add your types
    });

    /**
     * create user
     */
    it('Create user with null input should return Invalid Input exception', async () => {
      // the failing request
      const createRequest = {
        // ...
      }

      // provide the response you want (ValidationError for example)
      jest.spyOn(model, 'save').mockImplementationOnce(jest.fn(async () => {
        throw new Error(); // throw ValidationError or whatever error mongoose would throw
      }));

      expect(service.create(createRequest)).rejects.toThrow(); // validate error is thrown

      // ... validate method is called
      expect(model.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(model.save).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        validateOnSave: true
      });
    });

    it('Create user with good input should return User', async () => {
      // the good request
      const createRequest = {
        // ...
      };

      // provide the response you want (ValidationError for example)
      jest.spyOn(model, 'save').mockImplementationOnce(
        jest.fn(async () => data)
      );

      const result = await service.create(createRequest);
      expect(result).toStrictEqual(data); // or whatever mock object you provide

      // ... validate method is called
      expect(model.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(model.save).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        validateOnSave: true,
      });
    });
});
```

### Learn More

1. https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters
2. https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#the-built-in-validationpipe (recommend this, validation is kept completely away from database, then DB validation is more of a sanity check)
3. https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#unit-testing
4. https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing

### Note

Re-add any types that were stripped.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed suggestions, I was also considering real db connection with integration tests. I will revisit/check other available nest options.